# how to I can set friendly url for a list item?

Tags: sharepoint-server, codebehind

how to I can set friendly url for a list item?

I need set the Friendly Url in an item of a determined list

Example:

```
http://[Sitio]/[List]/[ListName]/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
```

to

```
http://[sitio]/[Pagina]/[ListItem]
```

Does anyone knows how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not easy task, you have to create an event receiver and use Managed Metadata terms.
to get this done.

- Create Site Columns & Content Type
- Bind an Event Receiver to Create the Navigation Term/Friendly URL
- Bind the Event Receiver to the Content Type
- Configure Your Navigation Term Set & Site Collection
- Deploy the Solution to your Site!
- Search Configuration
- Finally! Configure ListItemDisplay.aspx

Read this blog for details...[Friendly URLs for SharePoint List Items](http://www.softlanding.ca/blog/friendly-urls-for-sharepoint-list-items)

Or go below for codeplex version.

[Friendly URLs for SharePoint 2013 List Items](https://friendlyurlsforlistitemssp2013.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I can bind the EventReceiver with List Instance?